# when I call jsp by using ajax then jsp returns lots of extra contents specially all html tag

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, liferay-6

I am busy quite with my new project where I working on jPlayer, completely based on jQuery.
I am very new in jQuery so I am facing lots of problems but now I am little comfortable with jQuery.

My requirement is to access a absolute url if the given url is relative, for that I used some java code. Each and every thing is working well but to fetch the absolute url I used java code for that I used jsp page and execute that using ajax call. Problem is the value returning from jsp is having lots of extra datas, generally all the html tags. I saw this question is already asked by some person and the reply

"use servlet instead of jsp because jsp for presentation and this will output some html".
and my codes are:

```
function funAJAX(songURL){
    var path=document.getElementById("url").value,
        ext=songURL.split('.').pop(),  // trying to pull extension of link 
        xmlhttp, absUrl;

    //alert(path);

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    // code for IE6, IE5 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            // document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            //$("#tempUrl").html(xmlhttp.responseText);
            //storing val in div of id="tempUrl"
            // absUrl=$("#tempUrl").find("info").text();
            //fetching the link only 

            var v=xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert("value from ajax: " + v);

            if(ext == "mp3" || ext == "Mp3") {  // if absolute url then songUrl val will not change 
                //  alert("extension: "+ext);
                ext=ext;
            }
            else {  // if relative link then storing the val returned from ajax as absolute link 
                // alert("in else part");                               
                songURL=absUrl;
            }

            alert("i2: song url:   " + songURL); // this will execute after returning val from jsp because of ajax call 
        }
    };

    // alert("2: song url:   "+songURL); //this will execute before sending req to jsp page 

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "" + path + "/html/player/songURLManipulation.jsp?songURL=" + songURL, true);  //calling songURLManipulation.jsp with argument songUrl 

    xmlhttp.send();  //sending the req 
}
```

above is my jsp page and having lots of tag
"/>
this liferay problems but main thing is to implement jplayer
and my another jsp that one I am calling through ajax is

```
<%
    String songURL=request.getParameter("songURL"); 

    String location=null;

    if(songURL!=null) {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(songURL).openConnection());

        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
        con.connect();

        location = con.getHeaderField("Location");

        response.getWriter().print(location);

        out1.print(location);
    }

    //return location;

    System.out.println("from song manipulation.jsp: "+songURL);
%>
```

I achieved this one by using serveResource method and calling that method by ajax by using json object but my question is, is it really not achievable through jsp page return value if I call through above describe way.
It is really good to be part of this forum.

Answer (score 1):

my ajax code

```
function funAJAXServlet(songURL,servletURL)
{
    alert("from ajax fun");
    jQuery.ajax({
          url :servletURL,            
          data: {"songURL":songURL},
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",                                                                         //describe the type of value returned from serveResource class 
        success: function(data) {              
                                                                                                                //to put data data into div part of html and data is coming from serveResource class.
            var jsonobj=data.songUrlServlet;
           alert("from servlet ajax:  "+jsonobj);               
     }
    });

}
```

and my serveResource method

```
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response)

     {
        String songURL=request.getParameter("songURL"); 
        JSONObject jsobj=null;
        String location=null;
        HttpURLConnection con;
        System.out.println("songURL from serveResourceUrl servlet method: "+songURL);
        if(songURL!=null)
        {

                try 
                {
                con = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(songURL).openConnection());   
                con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
                con.connect();
                location = con.getHeaderField("Location");
                System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$4  location val: "+location);
                jsobj = JSONFactoryUtil.getJSONFactory().createJSONObject();
                if(location!=null)
                    jsobj.put("songUrlServlet",location);
                else 
                    jsobj.put("songUrlServlet","null");
                PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();                                          //writing to the client page
                writer.write(jsobj.toString());             
                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        //return location;
        else
        System.out.println("from song serveResource method: "+songURL);
     }
```

This is working fine.